# Why doesn't the compiler complain when returning a bad type?

Tags: java

Considering the function below, I noticed that the compiler doesn't signal any problems:

```
private static int returnTwoTypes() {
    int a = 1;
    if (a == 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 'a';
}
```

How come I can return both a `character` and an `int` when the function return type is `int`?

Comment: each `char` also represents an int. maybe that is the reason

Comment: A simpler example that works equally is `int a = 'a';`. That is, the `return` works because assignment also works.

Comment: @DanielPryden I played arround with many combinations to understand what is happening, I wanted a lower level explanation, thanks!

Comment: [jls-4.2.1 Integral Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) and *widening* conversion.

Comment: Easily promoted to int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `char` is an integral type that can be automatically promoted to an `int`. Therefore a method that returns an `int` can return a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

A character is technically a 16-bit unsigned integer, so it can be returned as an integer

Answer (score 1):

This concept is called **variable UpCasting** wherein a smaller memory type is automatically UpCasted and returned.

Here `char` is upcasted to `int` and returned